# how to parse json to get lodash score from a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to find out how to parse the url and put the names in an array and then to parse the json to get the lodash score and convert the score to a whole number. any help would be nice.

```
<head>
    <title> final</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <h3>The window.location object</h3>

<input type="button" value="Load new document" onclick="newDoc()">

<script>
function newDoc() {
    window.location.assign("https://api.npms.io/v2/package/lodash");
}

</script>
    <!--// JSON.parse(");-->
    <!--// displayfromJSON(lodash);-->
    <!--//     window.substring(0.9200443085079093);-->
    <!--// split(92)-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to fetch the npm package information of the lodash package and parse our the score or it?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0):

When you change the location to that url your page no longer exists...and neither does any of your script

Use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the data and then do what you want with it.

```js
fetch('https://api.npms.io/v2/package/lodash')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.score))
```

Comment: So if I add this code to my project then it will display the scores.

Comment: No it simply provides you access to the data. Open your browser console will see it there for now. Up to you to manipulate that data and turn it into html to display whatever you want